# VB script to open .exe file and perform 4 activities

Tags: vbscript

I have a tool based on .net. I need a vb script which would open this tool (.exe file) and then select 3 radio buttons, click on a button to browse a xml file stored in same folder and then click on invoke button. Is this possible? I am a complete fresher and just have this idea in mind for an automation. This is required as I have to perform the same steps daily.

I could find this code:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Users\abc\Desktop\folder\Tool.exe""")
```

Which is doing my task to open the .exe file perfectly. Can someone help/guide me in achieving the further steps?

Comment: We typically close questions like "How do i (write basically this whole thing)?", as they're too vague and open-ended.  If you have a problem with some code, that's what we're here for.  If your problem is that you have no code to speak of, that's what hired developers are for.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off making your tool work via the command line and having it accept arguments.

That way, you could use a .bat file to call your 'tool' passing in the arguments it needs and away you go.

These should get you started on your quest.

- [Creating a HelloWorld Console Application Using VisualBasic.NET](http://voices.yahoo.com/creating-helloworld-console-application-using-visualbasicnet-344987.html?cat=59)
- [How to Parse Command Line Parameters?](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/console-application/5177-how-parse-command-line-parameters.html)
- [What is a bat file](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/batfile.htm)

Comment: For the requirements he described he'd probably be better off with something like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). However, that's largely off-topic here.